# Recursion function in python- check if element in a list is already present and generate a new one

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursion function with python which checks for names in a list and gives out a new name. The name of csv to be checked can be formed using parameters comm and index passed to the function.
I wrote  the below function and expecting the output to be printed as string

```
csv_full_list=["mycsv_0","mycsv_1"]

def create_csv_name(comm,index):
    if comm+"_"+str(index) in csv_full_list:
        create_csv_name(comm,index+1)
    else:
        return comm+"_"+str(index)
print create_csv_name("mycsv",0)
```

> can anyone tel me why this function returning 
>   none type

instead

> of string.

Comment: what is the end condition ? your problem does not seem to be recursive in nature

Comment: It is. As I can pass only initial index.. for example index 0 passed in my example. so index 0 and 1 are already present in list in form of mycsv_0 and mycsv_1. The function starts by checking 0 and then 1 and if no name exist  after that. its gives out as output. for ex: mycsv_2

Comment: `create_csv_name(comm,index=+1)` ==> `create_csv_name(comm,index+1)`. Where's the stop condition of the recursion ?

Comment: check the list index with ‘in’, if its True

Comment: Also I like to add that this is a total abuse of recursion and not beautiful in the sense of the Zen of Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to increment the index to avoid endless recursion.

```
csv_full_list = ['mycsv_0', 'mycsv_1']


def create_csv_name(comm, index):
    global csv_full_list
    if comm + '_' + str(index) in csv_full_list:
        index += 1 # increment index by 1
        create_csv_name(comm, index=index)
    else:
        return '%s_%i' % (comm, index)


print(create_csv_name('mycsv', 0))
```

Comment: @RombySoft You have to for conventional purposes. Please take note that you don't pass any argument to fulfill the variable csv_full_list.

Comment: why is this function  returning None type. it shd return a string :(